# Django messages: how to change html structure?

Tags: django, django-messages

So I've got some really specific styling constraints for the messages, and I've pushed ::before and ::after as far as they will go. Beyond that what I really need is for the text of the message to be enclosed in a span tag, ideally with a settable class (it's just dumped in the div which is not great to begin with).

Is there any setting in Django, or any place I can go to restructure the html? I can't find any documentation for this (surely this is not an uncommon thing to customise).

The alternative is to use js, but I'd prefer to avoid cutting and pasting elements and content when it should be something that should be customisable.

What I've got is:

```
<div class="messages">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade show">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">x</a>
        [message text]
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want is:

```
<div class="messages">
    <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable fade show">
        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">
            <i class="close-icon"></i>
        </a>
        <span>[message text]</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In views.py I'm using `SuccessMessageMixin` in various places.

Comment: What messages? Do you mean the contrib.messages framework? That doesn't include any specific HTML at all, so it's hard to know what your question is asking.

Comment: The messages framework: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: I mean that's the thing, where is the html set?

Comment: The HTML is not set anywhere. The app does not provide any HTML at all.

Comment: Yes, but clearly it is outputting html. Where is it coming from?

Comment: The only HTML it can be outputting is whatever you have put into your own templates.

Comment: Okay, so what template is this coming from? A search of the project (using the classes) turns up nothing. That is the mystery I am trying to solve.

Comment: You’d often put the messages code in a base template so that the messages are shown on all pages on the site. If a search for `class="messages"` or `{% if messages %}` doesn’t find the template, you could use the debug toolbar which will show you the templates used by the view.

Comment: Yeah, I see what you are @DanielRoseman are saying. I was searching explicitly for "alert-success" but what was in the template as "alert-{{ message.tags }}". :-\ It's been a long day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as it was pointed out to me, this was my search fail. The html structure for the messages can usually be found in base.html (it seems like it is a standard place to set it up).

There is some good documentation here: https://django-advanced-training.readthedocs.io/en/latest/features/contrib.messages/